# How can I make multi thread program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.5, and I want to make multi-keystroke function.

I mean, I want to make a function that notices Ctrl+S and Q.

But my program doesn't notice it.

Here's my code:

```
import threading, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1160, 640), 0, 0)
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
pygame.display.flip()

def background():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL and event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    print('GOOD')

def foreground():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    print('HELLO_WORLD')
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

b = threading.Thread(name='background', target=background)

b.start()
foreground()
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `b.start()`, you let the program go into the infinite loop of listening Ctrl+S event. The event of key combination, once obtained in the `background` thread, will not be released back into the event queue. and the `foreground` function won't be able to capture and process it.

If you want your program to be able to process different key combination. You should let one function to listen to key press event, and dispatch the event to different processing functions.

Comment: Well, thank you for quick answering. But when I run that program, it notice Q, not Ctrl + S